# colour change of drop down children

Tags: html, css

simply put , i have a drop down menu with the list fields "press" and "map" however i can't seem to change the colour of them I seem to be able to change the colors of the main list items and everything else is looking great but there doesn't seem to be an option for the children and not sure how to create the items for it ... can someone help here is the html and css ...

```
<nav id="topnav">
    <ul class="clear">
      <li class="active first"><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="events.html">EVENTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="getinvolved.html">GET INVOLVED</a></li>
      <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
      <li class="last-child"><a class="drop" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="press.html">PRESS</a></li>
          <li><a href="map.html">MAP</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

and the css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'badaboom_bbregular';
    src: url('badabb__-webfont.eot');
    src: url('badabb__-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('badabb__-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('badabb__-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('badabb__-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('badabb__-webfont.svg#badaboom_bbregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
nav ul{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; font-family:'badaboom_bbregular';}

/* ----------------------------------------------Top Navigation-------------------------------------*/

#topnav{padding:10px 0;  clear:both; z-index:20;}
#topnav ul{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:1.9em;}
#topnav ul ul{z-index:9999; position:absolute; width:130px; text-transform:none;}
#topnav ul ul ul, #topnav ul ul ul ul{left:260px; top:0;}
#topnav ul li:last-child ul, #topnav ul li.last-child ul{right:0;}
#topnav ul.negative{left:-160px;}
#topnav li{position:relative; display:block; float:left; margin:0 0 0 20px; padding:0;}
#topnav li:first-child, #topnav li.first{margin-left:0;}
#topnav li li{width:100%; margin:0;}
#topnav li a{display:block; padding:0;}
#topnav li li a{display:block; margin:0; padding:10px 15px;}

#topnav ul ul{display:none;}
#topnav ul li:hover > ul{display:block;}

#topnav a{color:#c20505; font-weight:bold;}

#topnav li li a, #topnav li.active li a{color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold;}
#topnav li.active a, #topnav a:hover{color:#ffffff;}
#topnav ul li li:hover > a{color:#FFFFFF;}

#topnav li a.drop:hover {color:#FFF;}

#topnav li a.drop, #topnav li.active a.drop{padding-left:15px; background-image:url("images/dropdown_side.gif"); background-position:5px center; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

/* Top navigation for smaller resolutions */

#topnav form{display:block; height:30px; margin:0 auto; padding:0;}

#topnav form select option{display:block; margin:10px; padding:0; cursor:pointer; outline:none; border:none;}
```

Comment: use `#topnav > ul > li > ul > li {/*css here*/}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems here is that you're already applying styles to those elements, so you have to use the CSS rule of specificity to actually apply different styles to them.

@joyBlanks had it right in the comments, for the most part, but the issue with that one is that you're applying something already to all links on the page (#topnav a) and all links under list elements (#topnav li a) and all links under list elements that are nested in list elements (#topnav li li a) etc., so applying it to `#topnav ul > li > ul > li` will not affect the links inside those list elements (man this is getting wordy).

You will have to either change the other CSS properties that apply, or come up with something specific to the elements you want to change. I did the latter.

Here's the CSS I used:

```
#topnav ul > li > ul > li a{
    color:#c20505;
    font-size:13pt;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
```

I should mention here that the color is the only thing you asked about. The rest I changed just to look better in the fiddle - completely unnecessary.

I also added a generic background color (#aaa) so I could see the white text on the background. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zp1ryspj/